# A commutative ring with identity $R$ is a domain $\iff$ the cancelation law holds in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm reading Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra preliminary section about algebraic structures. It defines a comutative ring $R$ with identity as being a abelian group with $+$ and with $\cdot$ except for the inverse element of $(\cdot)$, and with distributivy of ($\cdot$) over $+$. It defines a domain as a ring such that for all $x,y\in R - \{0\}$, $xy \neq 0$. Then it states that a comutative ring with identity is a domain $\iff$ the cancelation law holds: $rx=ry, r\ne 0\implies x=y$.

Proof of ($\Rightarrow$): $rx-ry=r(x-y)=0 \Rightarrow x-y=0 \Rightarrow x=y$. 
I tried to prove the ($\Leftarrow$) part, but I don't know if my steps are right and wanted some verification: I'll proceed by contrapositive: let $r,x\in R - \{0\}$ with $rx=0$, then $rx = r\cdot 0$ and $x \ne 0$.

I'm just not really sure if I'm doing the negation of the affirmations correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks OK.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: In other words, if cacellation "fails" for some nonzero multiplier $a$, then $a$ is a zero "divisor", and conversely, given that $a$ is a zero divisor, we easily construct an example of cancellation failing.

Comment: Your definition of a commutative ring is incomplete: you also need the distributivity of multiplication over addition.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'll edit for completeness.